# Highlighting Alternate Table Rows With Varying Rowspans

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a `table` and the `rowspan` of the `td` varies so I am having trouble achieving what I want.

Here is was I currently have:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         table {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         }
         td{
         padding: 5px;
         border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
         }
         tbody{
         border-bottom: 2px solid black;
         }
         tr,td :not(:last-child){
             border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <td>Customer</td>
               <td>Date of Order</td>
               <td>Purcahsed Product Numbers's</td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="4">John Doe</td>
               <td rowspan=2>08/30/2018</td>
               <td>#5894895984</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>#5894895984</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>01/29/2018</td>
               <td>#32344</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>08/19/2019</td>
               <td>#85949854</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4">Jane Smith</td>
               <td>03/22/2019</td>
               <td>#0034003</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan=3>03/12/2016</td>
               <td>#938498544</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>#545635245</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>#00239029</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is what I want the table to look like: [image]

Is this possible with just html and css or would I need to use javascript/jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: via CSS you can draw the thicker line every 4rows with selector filtering row position and row spanning for the td's, but for the hilghting part, css will not be able to help. you can look for rowspan attribute but then can only select any next sibllings from there. JavaScript is required for background part.

Answer (score 0):

You can group different sections of your table using `tbody` elements, like this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
}

tbody {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

tr,
td :not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}

tbody:nth-child(2n+1) td {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer</td>
      <td>Date of Order</td>
      <td>Purcahsed Product Numbers's</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">John Doe</td>
      <td rowspan="2">08/30/2018</td>
      <td>#5894895984</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#5894895984</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01/29/2018</td>
      <td>#32344</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08/19/2019</td>
      <td>#85949854</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">Jane Smith</td>
      <td>03/22/2019</td>
      <td>#0034003</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">03/12/2016</td>
      <td>#938498544</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#545635245</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#00239029</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.highlightStart:even').each(function() {
      let startingRowspan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
      $(this).nextAll().addBack().addClass('highlight'); 
      $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0, startingRowspan-1).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer